# google app engine, java: perform action before dev server is killed

Tags: java, google-app-engine, kill

I am killing my Google App Engine dev server with `kill`. I would like to clean up some local changes before the server dies. How can I do it?

Comment: Why are you stopping the server with `kill -9`? (You generally cannot catch SIGKILL).

Comment: True, I can stop it with just `kill`.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Relying on this behavior is a very bad idea, in real life.

Comment: I don't need this for production environment, but for development. After one stops dev server, some steps need to be taken to run it again. I would like to automatize it.

Answer (score 0):

To kill dev server you can simply press `control-c` as [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver#Running_the_Development_Web_Server) state:

```
To stop the web server, press Control-C (on Windows, Mac or Linux).
```

Control-c is in Unix systems sends the SIGINT signal, which you can achieve manually via `kill -SIGINT <pid>`.

This **should** gracefully shutdown the server - in this case you can install a lifecycle listener to get called when server shuts down. Just implement the `contextDestroyed(..)` method as shown in [this example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/) and register it in your `web.xml`.

NOTE: such shutdown hook does NOT work on production server (verified). I never tried it on dev server, but it should work as this is plain Jetty.

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow and say how it worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, the problem is: `// App Engine does not currently invoke this method.` for contextDestroyed. Do you have any other ideas?